# How to add TimesStamp to document (ITextSharp, BouncyCastle)

Tags: c#, pdf, timestamp, itext, bouncycastle

Hi I want do add TimeStamp from authority server to Pdf by using ItextSharp, but I don't know how. I can only add Timestamp to PDF with digital signature, but I want add without it.

When I obtain TimeStamp from server it comes with certificate inside it, but it doesn't have primary key to sign, is there other way to sign without certificate or I need it for it and if Yes, how to obtain primary key to sign PDF with it.

Obtaining timestamp token is by Bouncy Castle library

```
private static TimeStampToken Timestamp(string InputPath, string annexFileName, stringsignedFileName,string UserTs, string PassTs, string UrlTs)
    {

      FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(InputPath);

        SHA1Managed sha = new SHA1Managed();
        byte[] hashedFile = sha.ComputeHash(stream);
        TimeStampRequestGenerator reqGen = new TimeStampRequestGenerator();
        reqGen.SetCertReq(true);

        TimeStampRequest request = reqGen.Generate(
            TspAlgorithms.Sha1, hashedFile, BigInteger.ValueOf(100));
      stream.Close();


      byte[] reqData = request.GetEncoded();
      ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
      ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 |
                                             SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;

      HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(UrlTs);
      httpReq.Method = "POST";
      httpReq.ContentType = "application/timestamp-query";
      httpReq.ContentLength = reqData.Length;
      httpReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserTs, PassTs);


      // Write the request content
      Stream reqStream = httpReq.GetRequestStream();
      reqStream.Write(reqData, 0, reqData.Length);
      reqStream.Close();

      HttpWebResponse httpResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse();

      // Read the response
      Stream respStream = new BufferedStream(httpResp.GetResponseStream());
      TimeStampResponse response = new TimeStampResponse(respStream);

      respStream.Close();
      response.Validate(request);
      TimeStampToken tsToken = response.TimeStampToken;

      Org.BouncyCastle.X509.Store.IX509Store x509Certs = tsToken.GetCertificates("Collection");
      ArrayList certs = new ArrayList(x509Certs.GetMatches(null));
      tsToken.Validate((Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate)certs[0]);

      return tsToken;


    }
```

Comment: Do you mean private key rather than primary key? If so the private key can only ever be known to the signer - in this case the timestamp authority. It is never included in the signature. There's an overview here explaining the principles of digital signatures (I know it's not for iText but it highlights the principles). [link](https://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-pdf-digital-signatures.aspx)

Comment: The pertinent section is  entitled "Signatures, Keys and Certificates"

Comment: Yes I mean primary key. What you send is just basic things about signatures. I have already functional digital signing, but with certificate and timestamp together. How can I sign PDF without certificate, but just add timestamp to PDF.

Comment: It is uncommon to use the term "primary key" in document signing. We sign with the signing certificate's "private key". There are two types of timestamps in  PDF. You can either pass the bytes of the ASN.1 encoded signed CMS to be signed by the timestamp server and put that in the Signature Contents (for a timestamped signature); or you can timestamp only the document digest thereby creating a DocTimestamp signature. It looks like you're trying to add a DocTimestamp. One reference is in A2  [here](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102700_102799/10277804/01.01.01_60/ts_10277804v010101p.pdf)

Comment: iText7 does have methods for adding a document timestamp but it looks like you want to go it alone so you will need to create a Signature form field and it's corresponding DocTimeStamp entry manually - in which case I'd recommend the PDF 2.0 spec (ISO 32000-2) - not free sadly. Or you may be able to figure it out from the ETSI link above. You're timestamp code looks reasonably. To check you can paste the returned bytes in [this webpage](https://lapo.it/asn1js/)

Comment: One last thing, I've encountered Timestamp servers that reject SHA-1 digests due to [recently found collisions](https://www.zdnet.com/article/sha-1-collision-attacks-are-now-actually-practical-and-a-looming-danger/). So I would use SHA-256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers.
I've tried a lot of ways to figure it out, but with no succes.
Now I'm using Syncfusion FileFormats Library and it works perfectly... It's not free sadly, but it can offer a lot of funcionality about files and it's security..

```
//Creates a new PDF document

PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

//Adds a new page

PdfPage page = document.Pages.Add();

//Creates a digital signature

PdfSignature signature = new PdfSignature(page, "Signature");

//Add the time stamp by using the server URI

signature.TimeStampServer = new TimeStampServer(new Uri("http://syncfusion.digistamp.com"), "user", "123456");

//Save and close the document

document.Save("Output.pdf");

document.Close(true);
```

Here is the sample how to add TimeStamp to Pdf by Syncfusion.